# How would I create a layout with multiple layout styles

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am trying to create a game launcher and for this I would have a couple of JPanels with different kinds of layout styles, at this moment I just don't know what to use as there are a lot of layout styles and they all have their own pros and cons.
This is what I have at the moment:
[image]

This is how  I did it:
This is the main frame, which has a couple of panels added.

```
public Frame() {
    main = new Background();
    menuPane = new MenuPane();

    main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    add(main);

    main.add(menuPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    setTitle("DelusionX Launcher");
    setSize(700, 500);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

This is the background panel

```
public Background() {
    try {
        backgroundImg = ImageIO.read(new File("./Images/Background.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(backgroundImg, (getWidth() - backgroundImg.getWidth(null)) / 2, 0, null);
}
```

This is the menu panel

```
public MenuPane() {
    this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.5f));
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    minimizeBtn = new Button();
    minimizeBtn.addActionListener(this);
    minimizeBtn.setIcon(minimizeImg);
    this.add(minimizeBtn, BorderLayout.EAST);
    closeBtn = new Button();
    closeBtn.addActionListener(this);
    closeBtn.setIcon(closeImg);
    this.add(closeBtn, BorderLayout.EAST);
}
```

and this is the button object

```
public Button() {
    setBorderPainted(false);
    setBorder(null);
    setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    setContentAreaFilled(false);
}
```

As you can see I also have added a minimize button, but for some reason it is behind the close button, I suppose.
This is what I want to achieve:
[image]
This is how I thought the panels should be, but I am not sure if that is the best/easiest way.

[image]
My question in short: How would I create an JFrame that looks like the second image?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do that for the next time, I thought I had provided enough information to answer this.

Comment: You've not yet provided enough information for me to see the code breaking in my IDE, which is when I read the rest of the words carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GridBagLayout` is one of the most flexible layout managers in the default API, it lets you get away with some amazing things if you're willing to try

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(100, 0, 0, 0);
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(new ProxyPane(400, 300, Color.RED), gbc);

            gbc.insets = new Insets(101, 1, 0, 1);
            gbc.weighty = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            add(new ProxyPane(400, 50, Color.YELLOW), gbc);

            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            gbc.weighty = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            add(new ProxyPane(300, 200, Color.GREEN), gbc);
        }

    }

    public class ProxyPane extends JPanel {

        private Dimension size;

        public ProxyPane(int width, int height, Color borderColor) {
            size = new Dimension(width, height);
            setBorder(new LineBorder(borderColor));
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return size;
        }

    }

}
```